# Java tomcat detect proxy settings under centOS Gnome wpad or pac

Tags: tomcat, proxy, gnome, http-proxy

I'm trying to detect Proxy Settings which are set as system wide or to the network configuration running on CentOS 7 for example:
[image]

I'm in a local DNS server and i can open wpad file in browser, and firefox is configured to use system wide settings works fine using proxy like:
[image]

on the webserver i have both wpad.dat or proxy.pac files and MIME types are set as required but tomcat cannot detect the proxy nor proxy vole library ... my strategy is OS_DEFAULT but it's not working...

How i can detect proxy settings under linux (Gnome) WPAD, PAC?